# Python - Regex - True Or False

Tags: python, regex

So what i want is for my code to understand if my input has a number in it or not, if it does it is meant to output "Correct" but if it doesn't then it would output "Incorrect" how can i actually make this work. So it knows if there is an integer in the input or not. Any help is appreciated

```
import re
yourString=input()
number = re.search(r'\d+', yourString).group()
if number == True:
  print("Correct")
else:
  print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: do you want to know if there is a digit in your string or if you string is an integer? you have the correct (well, mostly correct) code for contains an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects you have a bit of a subtle error.

The statement should not be `if number == True:` it should be `if number:`, the reason being the value number is tests as `True` if anything is matched, and is `None` if there are no matches.

i.e.

```
import re
yourString=input()
number = re.search(r'\d+', yourString)
if number:
    print("Correct")
    group = number.group()
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Note, somewhat bizarrely

```
import re
yourString=input()
number = re.search(r'\d+', yourString)
if number:
    print(number == True)
    group = number.group()
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

Prints false, so number is not the value true, it overrides `__bool__`. See [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**bool**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) for more information

Comment: ok thank you so much this is what i have been trying to figure out for a few days now and you have solved a giant problem for me thank you soooo much

Comment: Oops, if nothing returns, the group method will error. I have modified this again.

Comment: yeah i was going to ask a question about that but you just solved it for me thanks

Comment: Note, while `if number:` resolves to true, even in that block if you add `print number == True` that will print false, but the test function of the number object has been overridden. This is unusually complex functionality btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str.isdigit](http://%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), or the built-in string to number conversions such as [float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) and [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
def extractNumber(string):
    for word in string.split():
        try:
            # The float() function accepts a decimal string.
            # The int() function accepts an integer string.
            return float(word)
        except ValueError:
            pass

number = extractNumber(input())

if number is not None:
    print('Your number is: {}'.format(number))
else:
    print('No number found')
```

Comment: ok i tried it but i only recognises it if there is only an integer in the input. I want it to recognise it when it is in a sentence like "I am 20 years old"

Comment: `\d+` will match one to many occurrences of digits, then it will detect floats

Comment: Yes, you can parse floats with the `float` function above.

Answer (score 0):

the regex you're looking for is: `\w*[0-9]+\w*`. It accepts anything that contains at least one digit.

`\w*` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` meaning it will match any lower/upper -case letter, digit or `_` literally. It can occur 0 to many times in the string

`[0-9]+` matches one to many digits from 0 to 9.

Actually, if your intention is just to check whether the string has digits you are good to go just with `[0-9]+` that's the same of what you posted originally.

You can try and create regexes using this site [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)